# How call Web Essentials task in MSBuild ?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, teamcity, msbuild-task, web-essentials

Web essentials works great when build in VS, but seems no way to build/bundle (Scss/js,Html,Sprit) when call MSBuild (like team city).

I googled lot stuffs, but only find - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pta.Build.WebEssentialsBundleTask/ but it only support bundle, is there any other way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, I found http://madskristensen.net/, Mads Kristensen split Bundler & Minifier and Web Compiler from Web Essentials 2015, and it supported integrate with MSBuild process !!!!

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c

Comment: I have a similar question [Call Visual Studio 2017 Task Runner from MSBuild] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324556/call-visual-studio-2017-task-runner-from-msbuild) about calling from MSBuild **but only for Release builds**.  Is that what you did here? If so, I would appreciate it if you could you answer my question with details of your implementation.