# Call Visual Studio 2017 Task Runner from MSBuild?

Tags: webforms, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, web-essentials, task-runner-explorer

I am using the [Bundler & Minifier VS2017 extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier) for JavaScript and CSS minification and MSBuild for other components of my ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms solution.  Using Task Runner, I created an "After Build" binding so the minification happens after MSBuild. This extension updates the bundle in real time when source file changes are saved so I would like the extension to do its work only when a Release build is created.

I suppose there is no way to configure the binding so it only activates for a Release build so instead, is it possible to call Task Runner from MSBuild?  Maybe something like:

```
<Exec Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'" Command="<Task Runner Command Here>" />
```

Also, besides the [Visual Studio Marketplace page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.TaskRunnerExplorer) for the previous release and [this blog page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/06/task-runners-in-visual-studio-2015/), is there any real documentation for the Task Runner that is included in VS2017?

**UPDATE:** I found this [CLI WIKI](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/wiki#command-line-interface-net-core) & [this article](http://dotnetthoughts.net/bundling-and-minification-in-aspnet-core/) but when I install NuGet pkg I get "Could not install package 'BundlerMinifier.Core 2.0.238'. You are trying to install this pkg into a project that targets .NETFramework,Ver=v4.0" This approach not viable for a 4.0 target Web Forms solution? Not sure why it matters since minify happens at build time and not runtime.