# VSTS and Web Essentials

Tags: azure-devops

Im using Web Essentials 2013 for compiling LESS files and bundling JS/CSS/HTML files.

Is there any way to setup a build definition in Visual Studio Team Services Online that compiles and bundles my files?

Comment: Don't find the way to do it with Web Essentials 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you can upgrade to Bundler & Minifier for VS2015, which has MSBuild support.

[Bundler & Minifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier)

[Web Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler)

Some related threads:

[Command line tool for recompiling bundles](https://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/6182957-command-line-tool-for-recompiling-bundles)

[How call Web Essentials task in MSBuild ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112759/how-call-web-essentials-task-in-msbuild)